# How to avoid blinking effect after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-ads-api

I have integrated Google Ads in my application and when I call notifyDataSetChnaged, ads are blinking.

I tried following solutions -

```
   fun RecyclerView.disableItemAnimator() {
    var animator: RecyclerView.ItemAnimator? = home_article_recyclerview.getItemAnimator();
    if (animator is SimpleItemAnimator) {
        animator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }
}
```

And

```
 itemAnimator?.changeDuration = 0
```

But none of them are working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapter.

Comment: check this link it will help you!!!  https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/recyclerviews-views-are-blinking-when-notifydatasetchanged-c7b76d5149a2

Answer (score 1):

You should use DiffUtil to update data. 
Refer: [diffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once with solution :
myRecyclerView.disableItemAnimator()